# pdo select statement is not working as it should

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm tired of trying to find the error, solutions but I am not getting it any way,
the code seems ok for me.

I have this pdo statement below for a login system and I put the correct email and password but it **is always entering in this else condition here**:

```
      else //always entering here  
            {                   
              echo '<pre>';     //I was trying to see whats happening with printf
              print_r($result); //but this print_r is not showing nothing 
              echo '</pre>';

              echo ' Wrong Password';  //I always get this message   
            }
```

**My pdo statement:**

```
if(isset($_POST['sendLogin']))
{
  $f['email'] = $_POST['email'];
  $f['pass'] =  $_POST['pass'];

  $autEmail = $f['email'];
  $autpass = $f['pass'];
  $searchEmail = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where email = :email");  
  $searchEmail->bindValue(":email", $autEmail);  
  $searchEmail->execute();
  $rows = $searchEmail->fetchAll();
  $num_rows = count($rows);
  $result = $searchEmail->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  if($num_rows == 1)
   {

     if($autEmail == $result['email'] && $autpass == $result['pass'])
    {
           $_SESSION['result'] = $result;
           header('Location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
        }

   else //always entering here 
    {                   
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($result);
        echo '</pre>';
        echo ' Wrong Password';     
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: *"I have this pdo statement..."* AND => `mysql_*` --- Choose "one" API.

Comment: Thanks for your question..but where I'm mixing the mysql with PDO? I only see PDO here. That mysql_real_escape_string I already removed but its the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're counting the number of rows wrong.  Use `$num_rows = $searchEmail->rowCount();` to count the rows.

Comment: No problem!  Be sure to check it as correct :-)

Comment: But its so strange because the $num_rows I think it was working because when I write the email and click on submit the $num_rows returns 1 line..so it was correct, but the password was not working good. But now its working..the only thing bad is that I dont understand how its working only with this change. But thank you :)

Comment: count() counts an array while rowCount() is the pdo for counting the number from the SELECT statement.